# Kivy/Python rotates the display (test,buttons, pictures). Test programs that worked, are now rotated

Tags: python, rotation, kivy

I am learning Python & Kivy: (Life was a lot easier using assembly for embedded controllers).
Now the whole display is rotated 90 degrees CCW.  Demo programs that used to work are now displayed rotated.
Presumably I did something that set a permanent "rotate display" flag while running Python.  Where and how can I reset it?  I rebooted the computer but no improvement. 
Win-7 64. Python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a while back when I was learning Kivy.  I even left a frustrated comment on [a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQdGWeN51EE).

There's a file at `c:\users\[username]\.kivy\config.ini` which you need to modify or delete.

Comment: That was the problem!  I am surprised that an educational demo program would permanently change a configuration file.  I have tried many while trying to learn so I do not know which one it was.